# Python regex to match multiple times, store results separately

Tags: python, regex

I'm a network engineer, trying to dip my toes into programming. I got recommended to try Python.

What I'm trying to do is to save some specific data, matching a string with multiple lines with regexp. We got our data to work with stored in `SourceData`.

```
SourceData = '
ip route 22.22.22.22 255.255.255.255 TenGigabitEthernet0/1/0 1.1.1.1
ip route 33.33.33.33 255.255.255.255 TenGigabitEthernet0/1/0 1.1.1.1
ip route 11.22.33.44 255.255.255.255 TenGigabitEthernet0/1/0 1.1.1.1
ip route 11.11.12.11 255.255.255.255 TenGigabitEthernet0/1/0 1.1.1.1
ip route 11.11.13.11 255.255.255.255 TenGigabitEthernet0/1/0 1.1.1.1
ip route 11.11.14.0 255.255.255.255 TenGigabitEthernet0/1/0 1.1.1.1
ip route 44.44.44.0 255.255.255.0 TenGigabitEthernet0/1/0 1.1.1.1'
```

The number of lines stored in `SourceData` is always unknown. Could be 0 lines (empty) to unlimited lines.

I want to match all lines containing ipv4-addresses starting with 11.

This is what I've come up with as a start:

```
ip1 = re.search('11\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}', SourceData)
        if ip1:
            ip1 = ip1.group()
```

Verify:

```
>>> print ip1
11.22.33.44
```

OK, seems to work. The idea is that when the whole `SourceData` is matched, with the example provided, the final result for this case would be 4 matches:

```
ip1 = 11.22.33.44
ip2 = 11.11.12.11
ip3 = 11.11.13.11
ip4 = 11.11.14.0
```

Next to learn, how do I continue to check `SourceData` for more matches as described above, and how do I store the multiple matches for use later on in the code? For example, later in the code I would like to use the value from a specific match, lets say match number 4 (`11.11.14.0`).

I have read some guidelines for Python and Regex, but it seems I quite don't understand it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `re.findall` to return all of the matches

```
>>> re.findall(r'11\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}', SourceData)
['11.22.33.44', '11.11.12.11', '11.11.13.11', '11.11.14.0']
```

Answer (score 3):

Several methods, one of them being:

```
import re

string = """
ip route 22.22.22.22 255.255.255.255 TenGigabitEthernet0/1/0 1.1.1.1
ip route 33.33.33.33 255.255.255.255 TenGigabitEthernet0/1/0 1.1.1.1
ip route 11.22.33.44 255.255.255.255 TenGigabitEthernet0/1/0 1.1.1.1
ip route 11.11.12.11 255.255.255.255 TenGigabitEthernet0/1/0 1.1.1.1
ip route 11.11.13.11 255.255.255.255 TenGigabitEthernet0/1/0 1.1.1.1
ip route 11.11.14.0 255.255.255.255 TenGigabitEthernet0/1/0 1.1.1.1
ip route 44.44.44.0 255.255.255.0 TenGigabitEthernet0/1/0 1.1.1.1'
"""

rx = re.compile(r'^[^\d\n]*(11(?:\.\d+){3})', re.M)

lines = [match.group(1) for match in rx.finditer(string)]
print(lines)
```

This yields:

```
['11.22.33.44', '11.11.12.11', '11.11.13.11', '11.11.14.0']
```

---

The core here is

```
^            # match start of the line
[^\d\n]*     # NOT a digit or a newline, 0+ times
11           # 11
(?:\.\d+){3} # .0-9 three times
.+           # rest of the line
```

The rest is done via `re.finditer()` and a list comprehension.
See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/dkhgAy/2/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.findall` with a positive lookbehind to ensure that the correct address, just after `"ip route"`, is being matched:

```
import re
s = """
  ip route 22.22.22.22 255.255.255.255 TenGigabitEthernet0/1/0 1.1.1.1
  ip route 33.33.33.33 255.255.255.255 TenGigabitEthernet0/1/0 1.1.1.1
  ip route 11.22.33.44 255.255.255.255 TenGigabitEthernet0/1/0 1.1.1.1
  ip route 11.11.12.11 255.255.255.255 TenGigabitEthernet0/1/0 1.1.1.1
  ip route 11.11.13.11 255.255.255.255 TenGigabitEthernet0/1/0 1.1.1.1
  ip route 11.11.14.0 255.255.255.255 TenGigabitEthernet0/1/0 1.1.1.1
  ip route 44.44.44.0 255.255.255.0 TenGigabitEthernet0/1/0 1.1.1.1' 
 """
final_ips = re.findall('(?<=ip route\s)11[\d\.]+', data)
```

Output:

```
['11.22.33.44', '11.11.12.11', '11.11.13.11', '11.11.14.0']
```